# creating a window with createwindow() when clicking a menu command

Tags: c, winapi

I want to create a window with CreateWindow() when clicking on a menu item that will be a child of the main window. I know I can use DialogBox() or CreateDialog() but I want to use CreateWindow(). I'm using this code

resource.rc file

```
#include "resource.h"
IDM_MENU MENU
{
    POPUP "&Help"
    {
        MENUITEM "&About", IDM_HELP
    }
}
```

About window procedure

```
LRESULT CALLBACK AboutProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Main window procedure

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDM_HELP:
            {
                WNDCLASSEX wc;
                HWND hDlg;
                MSG msg;
                SecureZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
                wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
                wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
                wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
                wc.hIcon = (HICON)GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICON);
                wc.hIconSm = (HICON)GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICONSM);
                wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
                wc.lpfnWndProc = AboutProc;
                wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("AboutClass");          

                if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
                    break;

                hDlg = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("About"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 300, 200, hwnd, 0, wc.hInstance, 0);

                ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

                while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
                UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, wc.hInstance);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a good idea? Can you register more than one class to the same instance? Also, is it a good idea to assign the main window icons to this child window or should I load them each time? Will those icons be deleted when I call UnregisterClass() in IDM_HELP? I have tried this program and everything works and the icons still show in the main window after I close this child window. But I still wonder if it's ok to assign the main window icons to this window since I call UnregisterClass() after the child window closes

Comment: Actually, one question: do you want a *modal* window?

Comment: No I don't want a modal window

Comment: @Watts32a: Then you should NOT be implementing a secondary message loop *at all*.  Simply `ShowWindow()` the About window and be done with it. Let the window destroy itself when it is closed, but that is it.  Let the main message loop handle everything.

Comment: @Watts32a: Also, you do not need to call `UnregisterClass()` at all.  It will unregister automatically when the process ends. Call `RegisterClass()` one time only, either at program startup, or the first time you display the About window. You can use `GetClassInfo()` to know whether the class is already registered, or keep track of it yourself.  Think of what happens if the user wants to display the About window more than one time during the process's lifetime.  So let it re-use an existing class registration each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `CreateWindow/Ex()` instead of `CreateDialog()`/`DialogBox()`.  And there is nothing wrong with running your own modal message loop, as long as you implement it *correctly*.  For instance, take heed of this warning:

[Modality, part 3: The WM_QUIT message](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393)

> The other important thing about modality is that a WM_QUIT message always breaks the modal loop. Remember this in your own modal loops! If ever you call  the PeekMessage function or the GetMessage function and get a WM_QUIT message, you must not only exit your modal loop, but **you must also re-generate the WM_QUIT message (via the PostQuitMessage message) so the next outer layer will see the WM_QUIT message and do its cleanup as well**. If you fail to propagate the message, the next outer layer will not know that it needs to quit, and the program will seem to "get stuck" in its shutdown code, forcing the user to terminate the process the hard way.

The example you showed is not doing that, so you would need to add it:

```
ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

do
{
    BOOL bRet = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
    if (bRet > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        if (bRet == 0) 
            PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam); // <-- add this!
        break;
    }
}
while (1);

UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, wc.hInstance);
```

However, your modal window should NOT be using `WM_QUIT` just to break its modal loop, as doing so would exit you entire application!  Use a different signal to make your modal loop break when the window is closed.  For example:

```
ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

while (IsWindow(hDlg) && (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK AboutProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, a modal window is supposed to disable its owner window, and then re-enable it when closed.  Your example is not doing that either, so that needs to be added as well:

```
ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
EnableWindow(hwnd, FALSE); // <-- add this
...
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK AboutProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EnableWindow(GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER), TRUE); // <-- add this
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The [Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) blog has a whole series of posts on how to work with modal windows.

[Modality, part 1: UI-modality vs code-modality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050218-00/?p=36413)

[Modality, part 2: Code-modality vs UI-modality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050221-00/?p=36403)

[Modality, part 3: The WM_QUIT message](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393)

[Modality, part 4: The importance of setting the correct owner for modal UI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050223-00/?p=36383)

[Modality, part 5: Setting the correct owner for modal UI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050224-00/?p=36373)

[Modality, part 6: Interacting with a program that has gone modal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050228-00/?p=36343)

[Modality, part 7: A timed MessageBox, the cheap version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050301-00/?p=36333)

[Modality, part 8: A timed MessageBox, the better version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050304-00/?p=36273)

[Modality, part 9: Setting the correct owner for modal UI, practical exam](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110121-00/?p=11703)

[The correct order for disabling and enabling windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040227-00/?p=40463)

[Make sure you disable the correct window for modal UI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061102-02/?p=29143)

**Update**: based on your comment that "No I don't want a modal window", you can ignore everything said above.  All of that applies to modal windows only.  Since you do not want a modal window, simply remove the secondary loop altogether and let the main message loop handle everything.  Also, you do not need to call `UnregisterClass()`. It will unregister automatically when the process ends. Call `RegisterClass()` one time, either at program startup, or at least the first time you display the About window. You can use `GetClassInfo/Ex()` to know whether the class is already registered, or keep track of it yourself. Think of what happens if the user wants to display the About window more than one time during the process's lifetime. So let it re-use an existing class registration each time.

Try this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK AboutProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDM_HELP:
                {
                    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
                    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
                    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
                    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("AboutClass");          

                    if (!GetClassInfoEx(wc.hInstance, wc.lpszClassName, &wc))
                    {
                        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
                        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
                        wc.hIcon = (HICON)GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICON);
                        wc.hIconSm = (HICON)GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICONSM);
                        wc.lpfnWndProc = AboutProc;

                        if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
                            break;
                    }

                    HWND hDlg = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("About"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 300, 200, hwnd, 0, wc.hInstance, 0);

                    if (hDlg)
                        ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                }
                break;
            }
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for EnableWindow(GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER), TRUE); I wanted to make the window modal before but I used EnableWindow(GetParent(hwnd), TRUE); in WM_CLOSE of AboutProc and that didn't work. Both the  while(IsWindow(hDlg) && (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)) {TranslateMessage(&msg); DispatchMessage(&msg);} and the do {...} while(1); close the whole program. I added a message box after the loop while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0) {TranslateMessage(&msg); DispatcchMessage(&msg);} and the message pops up after I close child window, so I'm assuming the loop terminates safely

Comment: You seem to be confused about the purpose of a message pump then. It's not reuired for every window, it's just what provides the main loop of your program. Get rid of the whole inner `GetMessage()` loop and just manager your new window yourself.

Comment: I can remove the message loop from IDM_HELP and the child window shows up fine but when I close it the whole application closes including the owner. If I have the message loop there only the child closes which is what I want. Btw, what happens when the IDM_HELP loop starts? Does the main window loop get suspended till the IDM_HELP loop ends?

Comment: @andlabs: A code-modal window blocks code until the window is closed. That requires a secondary message loop.  Remember, there is a difference between code-modal and UI-modal.  You are describing UI modality.  I'm describing code modality.

Comment: @Watts32a: closing a modal window is not supposed to exit the entire app.  If it is, you do not have your message loops set up correctly.

Comment: If I leave the code exactly like in my original post everything works as expected. I only have 2 loops. One in WinMain and one in IDM_HELP. They're both similar while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0) {TranslateMessage(&msg); DispatchMessage(&msg);}  If I add any of the two loops you suggested in IDM_HELP(do {...} while (1); or the other one) the entire app exits

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that; I think this guy just wants to open a secondary window (a toolbox, say) and doesn't know that the message pump isn't part of the window itself. It sounds like he neither wants it code modal nor UI modal; see my question in a comment to the original question.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I found the problem. Your do {...} while(1); loop works but the line if (bRet == 0) PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam); // <-- add this! needs to change to if (bRet == WM_QUIT) PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Do I need the loop in IDM_HELP whether the child window is UI modal or non UI modal?

Comment: @Watts32a: the return value of `GetMessage()` is a BOOL, not a message ID. Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx): "*If the function retrieves the WM_QUIT message, the return value is zero.*".

Comment: @Watts32a: As for modality, you need the secondary message loop only if you implement the About window to be **code-modal**, meaning it blocks the calling code until the window closes, and thus is also blocking the main message loop. If you just want **UI-modal** without **code-modal**, you would go through all of the same motions as **code-modal** except not use the secondary loop, allowing the main message loop to handle the window, thus the calling code is not blocked. You still have to disable/enable the owner window either way, that is what makes it modal in general.

Comment: @Watts32a: **UI-modal** only blocks the UI but not the calling code.  **Code-modal** blocks the UI and the calling code.

Comment: @Watts32a: based on your comment that you do not want a modal window, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Your original do {...} while(1); loop was correct. The reason my entire app was exiting when I closed child window was cause of the PostQuitMessage() in WM_DESTROY of AboutProc(). WM_DESTROY case in AboutProc had to be deleted. When I closed child window, the PostQuitMessage() in AboutProc posted a WM_QUIT message, which ended the inner loop. Then the line if (bRet == 0) PostQuitMessage(0); posted another WM_QUIT which was received by the WinMain loop which ended the entire app.

Comment: @remy Lebeau The reason my original code worked was cause when I closed child window, the PostQuitMessage() in WM_DESTROY of AboutProc() posted a WM_QUIT, which ended the inner loop. But the inner loop didn't post another WM_QUIT, so control was transferred to WinMain loop, but that's not the correct way to do it because PostQuitMessage() in WM_DESTROY of AboutProc() shouldn't be there. PostQuitMessage() is for exiting the entire app and shouldn't be called when closing a child window

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I noted one  more interesting thing. After deleting WM_DESTROY in AboutProc(), when you close child window, the inner loop doesn't end. I have a MessageBox() after the inner loop and it doesn't pop up when closing child window. The inner loop only ends when you close the entire app, which then posts another WM_QUIT to also end the WinMain() loop. Is that how code modal is supposed to work?

Comment: Did you add the `case WM_CLOSE: DestroyWindow(hwnd);` portion to `AboutProc()`, and the `IsWindow()` check in the inner loop? Alternatively, maybe move `DestroyWindow()` outside of the inner loop, and then use `IsWindowVisible()` is break the loop. Or, just have the About window set a `bool` flag when it closes, and break the inner loop on that value.  Or, just remove the inner loop altogether, since you said you don't want a modal window to begin with.

Comment: The case WM_CLOSE: DestroyWindow(hwnd); was alredy there in AboutProc(). I added IsWindow() now to inner loop and everything works correct. The inner loop ends when I close child window

Comment: 403 Forbidden. all links are dead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `CreateWindow()`. You can do *anything* in your event handler. Using `DialogBox()` just gives you a modal loop for free (so your main window cannot be interacted with until the dialog box is closed).

Yes, you can register multiple window classes. You are free to register all your window classes in advance; you do not need to call `RegisterClass()` and `UnregisterClass()` each time someone clicks your menu item.

I'm not sure if `UnregisterClass()` frees the various GDI resources allocated to your window class; anyone who knows the answer is free to comment.